# How do I reverse list under the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I want to reverse a list but it is not ordinary list. It has itself list items. For Example:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I have made a program and you can see it but it does not giving me correct output.

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    if len(L) > 1:
        x=len(L)
        i=0
        for i in range(x):
            L[i].reverse()
    else:
        L.reverse()
    return L
```

and after execution it is giving this result:

```
[[2, 1, 0], [3, 2, 1]]
```

However this output is wrong, the correct one is:

```
[[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Please I just missing very ordinary thing but as I am a noise programmer so I do not have enough knowledge. Thank you so much for your help.

**PLEASE CHECK YOUR CODE WITH -VE NUMBERS**

Comment: WHAT ARE "-VE NUMBERS"

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehension :

```
l = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]

c = [x[::-1] for x in l[::-1]] # [[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

I'm not sure what you have tried but :

```
l = [[1, 2], [3, -4], [-5, 6, 7]]
c = [x[::-1] for x in l[::-1]] # [[7, 6, -5], [-4, 3], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: Dear sir, your program is wrong! just check the given list

    [[1, 2], [3, -4], [-5, 6, 7]]

for this input output should be 
    [[7, 6, -5], [3, -4], [2, 1]]

but it is giving this output

    [[7, 6, -5], [-4, 3], [2, 1]]

Comment: Why second element is not reversed?!

Comment: Because it is sorted but reverse order. Please look the output which I have given in program.

Comment: @DrQaimMehdi The question has nothing to do with sorting. It's only about reversing. Which this answer does (and all others do, too).

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and indexing:

```
old_list = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
# reversed(old_list) = [[1,2,3],[0,1,2]]
new_list = [item[::-1] for item in reversed(old_list)]
new_list
# [[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be reversing the list containing the lists *in all cases*, not just if the condition `len(L) > 1` is `False`, just make a short change to:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    if len(L) > 1:
        x=len(L)
        i=0
        for i in range(x):
            L[i].reverse()
    L.reverse()
```

Since this function changes the list and sub-lists *in-place*, you don't need the `return` statement (`L.reverse()` returns `None`).

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution using list comprehension, where `l` is your initial list:

```
In [5]: list(reversed([list(reversed(x)) for x in l]))
Out[5]: [[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```